# C++ Vectors Problem

Tags: c++, stl, vector

well i have most probably an extremly stupid problem but could not figure it out and I m  about to lose my sanity hope someone can help

```
vector<CvMat*> sample;
for(int x = 0; x < 29; x += 2)
{
    for(int b = 0; b < 22; b += 2)
    {
      cvmSet(g, 0, b, cvmGet(NormalVector, 0, x + b));
      cvmSet(g, 0, b + 1, cvmGet(NormalVector, 0, x + b + 1));
    }
    sample.push_back(g);
}
```

Well i m using OpenCv for some matrix calculations basiacllay what I m doing is I m creating some small matrices from a big matrix and putting them into a Vector called "sample" in here.First loop is just a counter based thing and second loop for creating the small matrices after the second loop i m putting them to the vector

But the problem is after these loops when i try to reach one of the matrices in the vector I always get the one that was put into the vector at last.
I use these methods to access the vector elements 
sample[0];
sample.at(6);
For these two I get the same matrix that was added to the vector at the end .What is the thing I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `sample` vector is a list of *pointers*, you will need to make sure that you create a new instance of `CvMat` for each element that you add to the vector. Otherwise, it sounds like all your elements are pointing to the same thing (`g`).

If `CvMat` has a copy constructor, you may be able to fix it by doing this:

```
vector <CvMat> sample;
for(int x =0 ; x<29; x+=2) {
    // ...
    sample.push_back(*g);
}
```

This creates a vector of `CvMat` *objects*, and the `push_back(*g)` makes a copy of the matrix and pushes it on to the back of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector < CvMat*> sample;
```

is a vector of pointers to CvMat, and you are continously pushing '`g`' into it. You need to be creating new instances of `CvMat` and adding those to your vector, not adding '`g`' to it every time.